# Python Calculator results are not being displayed

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

so i was trying to make a python calculator, that opens like a window, but before the calculations i was trying to make it display the numbers that i clicked, everything was normal, the append, the list, everything was normal until it had to display the actual numbers, where it displays **nothing**, i tried to make change the label to "hi" for example to see if the problem is with the list, but nothing is being displayed, can someone help me get numbers to be displayed in the "results" area? here is my code:

```
root = tk.Tk()

color = '#263D42' 
numbers = []

Background = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=601, bg=color)
Background.pack()

resultBack = tk.Canvas(root, height=150, width=400, bg="#E4E0E0") 
resultBack.place(x=50, y=1)



root.title('Calculator')
root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='plus.ico'))
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
root.geometry("500x600")


for number in numbers:
    label = tk.Label(root, text="hi", bg="black")
    label.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1) #frame

def addOne():
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
     widget.destroy()
    numbers.append('1')
    for number in numbers:
        print(number)
        label = tk.Label(root, text=number, bg="black")
        label.pack()
    print(numbers)



one = tk.Button(root, text="1", padx=10, pady=5, fg="#000000", bg="#ffffff", command=addOne)
one.place(x=30, y=30)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You call for number in numbers when you haven't added anything to it.

Comment: because stuff get added to "numbers" when i press the buttons, so when i press the buttons, the get displayed, in a calculator its empty at launch, i also tried adding stuff in the "numbers" list to test if  thats the problem, nothing got displayed so that is not the problem

Comment: Just as a side point, its generally easier to either focus on the front end (in your case tkinter) or the backend (in your case the actual calculator). Trying to do both at the same time just makes things more difficult

Comment: right now i am trying to focus on the front end, i will focus on the backend as soon as i get the user interface working well, i have yet to start working on the backend

Comment: All of those Labels you are adding are appearing entirely outside of the visible area of the window.  You have forced the window to be a fixed size, so it cannot enlarge itself to make them visible, yet its content area is entirely filled by `Background`.  You need to add the Labels to one of the containers (`resultBack` or `frame`) that you have placed on top of the background, rather than to the root window itself.

Comment: so i removed the resize lock, now it shows black blocks when i click on "1", idk what part of the code i should change to fix it or change where it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be creating and deleting your labels like that; you can just change them.
Maybe try something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

numbers = []

root.title('Calculator')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
root.geometry("500x600")

label_text = tk.StringVar()
label_text.set('hi')
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_text)
label.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1) #frame

def addOne():
    numbers.append(1)
    work = ""
    for i in numbers:
        work+=str(i)
    label_text.set(work)

one = tk.Button(root,
    text="1",
    padx=10,
    pady=5,
    fg="#000000",
    bg="#ffffff",
    command=addOne)
one.place(x=30, y=30)

root.mainloop()
```

That should get the numbers showing up.  StringVars are your friend for these sorts of things.  As you update them, tk automatically updates the widget they are attached to.
From here, you will probably want to move things around to look better etc. and you probably don't want to have to add a method for each button (addTwo, addThree, addFour etc.)  Let us know if you need more help.